# Существует ли удобный формат для сохранение конфигурационных файлов для Python, удобный как для разрабочика так и для простого пользователя?

Tags: python

Нужно удобное решение для хранения файлов конфигурации, которые будут использоваться пользователями программы.
Нужна возможность работать с комментариями к файлам. Решение должно быть максимально читабельным. Сейчас склоняюсь к yaml. Может быть есть подходящее решение?

Comment: я в таких случаях использую YAML. У него IMO только один "недостаток" - необходимо установить дополнительный модуль...

Comment: https://hjson.github.io/

Comment: все зависит от пользователей. yaml/toml хорош, json тоже неплох (visual studio code прям хорошо использует). xml для любителей джавы (куча редакторов-валидаторов-парсеров-документации). если немного, то можно и ini файл использовать. Но я бы прикрутил ui к редактированию конфигов и тогда для обычных пользователей красивый интерфейс, для продвинутых - ручное редактирование, а им обычно побоку.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ini

Comment: @КириллМалышев это прям TOML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме названных вариантов есть ещё библиотека sd-format доступная на pip.
Данные там сохраняются в собственном формате записи файлов конфигурации - sd. Подойдёт она только Pyton3. С комментариями там можно работать.
Все комментарии сохраняются во вложенном словаре, даже комментарии к sd файлам.
Что там доступно: Работа с комментариями,сохранение данных с несколькими уровнями вложенности 'dict', запись настроек в  виде пары ключа и значения, использование в качестве значения списков 'list',  не задокументированная возможность использовать список внутри списка в качестве значения, возможность указывать много строчное строковое значение 'str'. Точное описание и примеры можно посмотреть здесь:
[sd-format](https://pypi.org/project/sd-format/#description)

Comment: [Репозиторий на github](https://github.com/aleks-daliton/sd) создан неделю назад, в репозитории лежат не исходники, а пакеты tar.gz и whl. В "живой природе" скорее всего нигде еще не используется. Мое оценочное мнение - очередной велосипед. Думаю, лучше использовать более зрелые решения, перечисленные в соседнем ответе.

Comment: Использую его уже давно, с первых версий. На гите видимо недавно выложили. Код нуждается в рефакторинге, но работает без багов

Comment: Смотрите: https://pypi.org/project/sd-format/#history На pypi впервые выложено 12 августа, т.е. тоже неделю назад. Если вы используете дольше, значит вы автор проекта (иначе где бы вы взяли этот sd-format, если не на pypi или на гитхабе), и ответ даете для его рекламы. Это в принципе подходит под формулировку тревоги "**спам** - Рекламирует продукт или услугу, [не раскрывая при этом причастность автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)."

Comment: "иначе где бы вы взяли этот sd-format, если не на pypi или на гитхабе" - конечно автор мог выложить где-то на форумах, а вы оттуда скачать, но гугл по запросу "python sd-format" не дает никаких внятных результатов, кроме pypi и github, поэтому я делаю вывод, что проект до 12 августа нигде не выкладывался, и с высокой долей вероятности вы и есть автор проекта)

Comment: Какой-то не дружелюбный подход здесь. Ответил в одном месте. Посоветовал человеку использовать Pycharm для поиска бага в его коде, объяснил как. Удалили мой ответ. Здесь строят какие-то теории заговора и минусят((((

Comment: Ок, безотносительно авторства проекта, почему не следует его использовать: 1 - на github выложены пакеты вместо исходников, делаем вывод, что автор не знает как пользоваться github. Вероятно, автор - начинающий разработчик. 2 - вы пишете, что работает без багов. Во-первых, отсутствие чего-то нельзя ни доказать, ни опровергнуть. Во-вторых - в проекте отсутствуют юнит тесты как таковые, поэтому вообще нельзя сделать никаких выводов о работоспособности проекта.

Comment: По поводу совета использовать PyCharm для отладки: это можно написать почти под любым вопросом, поэтому ценность такого ответа стремится к нулю. Это можно было бы написать комментарием, но на ответ это точно не тянет. Поэтому по результатам голосования в очереди проверки ваш ответ был удален.

Comment: Давайте не гадать, а напишем автору и попросим его дать свои комментарии?
Я скачал, попробовал. Вроде норм. Сохраняет и собирает аналогично

Comment: Могу пример своего тестирования выложить

Comment: Меня предыдущие комментарии тоже в сомнения вгоняют, попробую ещё немного погоняю её

Comment: @АлександрБашловкин можно написать автору на гитхабе issue, чтобы он нормально оформил репозиторий и добавил какие-то хотя бы минимальные тесты. То что вы потестировали вручную - это неплохо, но я не думаю что имеет смысл выкладывать результаты тестирования здесь, это не совсем соответствует формату stackoverflow.

Comment: По поводу использования пайчарма. Это зачастую единственно верное решение. И для человека, если он поймёт как его использовать это может быть реальная польза на долгие годы.

Comment: @student_007 тем не менее, этот совет не является полноценным ответом.

Comment: @insolor наши мнения не совпадают

Comment: @student_007 я не думаю, что тут есть что обсуждать. Рекомендую почитать этот раздел справки: [Как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: Вот цитата из правил: __Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным__

Comment: @student_007 удаление вашего ответа к другому вопросу — это оффтопик в рамках данного вопроса. Если у вас есть претензии к удалению вашего ответа, вы можете задать вопрос [на мете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) (когда у вас будет хотя бы 5 баллов репутации), либо написать через форму обратной связи (внизу сайта ссылка "связаться с нами")

Comment: Попробовал ещё поиздеваться над данными. По результатам тестов багов не обнаружил. Файлы получаются идентичными, данные консистентны. Попробую использовать.

Answer (score 6):

Подытожу так сказать.
Варианты хранения:

- .ini файл (https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) - быстро, просто, доступно "из коробки". Идеально, для небольших проектов.
- .toml файл (либа https://pypi.org/project/toml/) - более гибкое чем INI решение за счет поддержки разных типов данных ("TOML включают DateTime , местное время , массивы , числа с плавающей запятой и даже шестнадцатеричные значения").
- .yaml файл (либа https://github.com/beetbox/confuse) - стильно, модно, наиболее читабельно.

Все перечисленные варианты, вместе с примерами использования - https://hackersandslackers.com/simplify-your-python-projects-configuration/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/637354)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics согласен, поправил.

Comment: А что насчет json и xml? :)

Comment: @gil9red так они менее читабельные, чем перечисленные выше. Если уж делать - то сразу что-нибудь нормальное использовать. Хотя как вариант, конечно, имеет право на существование.